# How can I unit test my overridden DbContext.SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6, nunit

I have overridden the `SaveChanges()` method to call a stored procedure after calling `base.SaveChanges()`. The stored procedure is in a repository that I can mock out easily enough, but how do I prevent the DbContext from actually saving the entity to the database?

**Update**
I should mention also that I'm wrapping the two actions in a transaction like this:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    private readonly IProcRepository _procRepository;

    public MyDbContext(IProcRepository procRepository, string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        _procRepository = procRepository;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var stateEntries = 0;

        using (var dbContextTransaction = Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                stateEntries = base.SaveChanges();
                _procRepository.MyStoredProcedure();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
        return stateEntries;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan, that appears to show how to mock DbContext. I want to test functionality I added to DbContext and mock out it's dependencies or prevent it from using them somehow.

Comment: what about intercepting? check IDbInterceptor as a base, and lots of derived interfaces which you can override and inject dbacontext to change behavior...

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan, interesting idea, but I'd still need to have a connection to the database for it to work, correct?

Comment: If you *only* care about the call to your stored procedure mock, then you can simply have the mock throw a known exception when it is invoked.  This will prevent the code from proceeding on to call the `base.SaveChanges`.  Of course, you may care that `base.SaveChanges` is actually invoked in which case this won't solve your problem...

Comment: @forsvarir, that's a good thought, but I misspoke in my original post. I'm actually calling the stored procedure _after_ `SaveChanges()` and both are in a transaction.

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?  The only way I can think to do this is with a mocking framework like JustMock or TypeMock (both are paid).  I don't think you can accomplish this with any free mocking frameworks.  In all of my code where we are actually connecting to the database is where we stop unit testing as it is not isolated.  Other option is to wrap everything in an interface.

Comment: @JCisar, I am using Moq

Comment: @adam0101 not sure you will be able to do this with Moq (thats what I use and we just don't test this).  If you are really set on getting this tested I would look into JustMock or TypeMock as they allow you to mock everything.